# how to override framework xml

Tags: magento2, xml, magento-core

Is there any way to override core XML file like this

```
vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/fa.xml
```

at this file, we have some hidden characters that should be removed or replaced because that, I need a way to override the XML file or help me to find a class that loaded fa.xml

Comment: You can check similar question here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104541/how-to-override-en-xml-in-zend-locale-data-with-custom-module

Comment: @SejalShah it's for mg1 not mg2